# Squeel evaluating a string as a keypath for joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, closures, squeel

Here's what I'd really like to do:

```
Outage.joins{eval "unit.plant"}
```

I'm going to have **a string** that represents **a squeel keypath**.  I'd like to send this string into a join statement.

But here's what I get as an error:

```
#<Class:0x639e328>: unknown class: Squeel::Nodes::Function
```

I've tried:

```
Outage.joins{"unit.plant"}
```

But that does not work... what am I missing?

I don't see any documentation on this on the github page: https://github.com/ernie/squeel/

Thank you for any help!

**Update:**
I've found a really confusing way to pull this off:

```
("unit.plant".split ".").map{ |x| x.to_sym }.reverse.inject{ |acc, x| { x => acc } }
```

This will output:

```
{:unit=>:plant}
```

This can be passed into the joins squeel function.  I'm sure there has to be a better way than to construct nested symbols :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Outage.joins{Squeel::Nodes::KeyPath.new("unit.plant".split("."))}
```

*Source: [KeyPath Docs](https://github.com/ernie/squeel/blob/master/lib/squeel/nodes/key_path.rb#L21)*

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly... I looked that over in the docs a few times but I didn't connect that I could just pass it into the constructor like that.  I'm still a bit of a Ruby n00b in some areas, but PHP will do that to you!

Comment: There's a drawback, it cannot be chained with outer/inner like `Outage.joins{Squeel::Nodes::KeyPath.new("unit.plant".split(".")).inner}`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, it can be chained with outer/inner:

```
strs = "unit.plant"
Outage.joins{strs.split(".").inject((strs.present? ? self : nil), :__send__)}

# chain with inner
# Outage.joins{strs.split(".").inject((strs.present? ? self : nil), :__send__).inner}
```